# Quill Js not working inside my content body

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I'm using Quill Js for rich editor for my blog content, when I edit inside my rich editor textaria then I can see work successful, but when I publish my blog then nothing happened on the content, just publish a plane text, I don't know why!

I'm using `next js`

I have tried by this way.

`_document.js` file

```
class MyDocument extends Document {
  render() {
    return (
      <Html lang="en">
        <Head>
          <meta charSet="URF-8" />
          <meta
            name="viewport"
            content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"
          />
          <link
            href="https://cdn.quilljs.com/1.0.0/quill.snow.css"
            rel="stylesheet"
          ></link>
          <script src="https://cdn.quilljs.com/1.3.4/quill.js"></script>
          <link
            href="//cdn.quilljs.com/1.3.6/quill.core.css"
            rel="stylesheet"
          ></link>
        </Head>
        <body>

        </body>
      </Html>
    );
  }
}

export default MyDocument;
```

I have import those library

then I have tried code like this:

`BlogCreate.js` file

`const ReactQuill = dynamic(() => import("react-quill"), { ssr: false });`

```
<div className="form-group">
                <ReactQuill
                  modules={BlogCreate.modules}
                  formats={BlogCreate.formats}
                  value={body}
                  placeholder="Write something amazing..."
                  onChange={handleBody}
                />
              </div>
```

I have import some of `modules` and `formats`

by this way:

```
BlogCreate.modules = {
  toolbar: [
    [{ header: "1" }, { header: "2" }, { header: [3, 4, 5, 6] }, { font: [] }],
    [{ size: [] }],
    ["bold", "italic", "underline", "strike", "blockquote"],
    [
      { list: "ordered" },
      { list: "bullet" },
      { indent: "-1" },
      { indent: "+1" },
    ],
    [{ align: [] }],
    ["link", "image", "video"],
    ["clean"],
    ["code-block"],
  ],
};

BlogCreate.formats = [
  "header",
  "font",
  "size",
  "bold",
  "italic",
  "underline",
  "strike",
  "blockquote",
  "list",
  "bullet",
  "link",
  "image",
  "video",
  "code-block",
];
```

Any Suggestion Please.